# Issue with firebase query

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift2

My query:

```
let query = recentRef.queryOrderedByChild(FRECENT_GROUPID).queryEqualToValue(group_id)
query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

And database structure is :

[image]

And my query looks like:

```
(/Recent {
    ep = fb343534ca520c70fe35b0a316ea8e4c;
    i = groupId;
    sp = fb343534ca520c70fe35b0a316ea8e4c;
})
```

and getting `Snap (Recent) <null>` when I `print(snapshot)`.

Its strange that it was working fine but now its suddenly stopped working.

**EDIT:**

Complete JSON:

```
{


 "Message" : {
    "fb343534ca520c70fe35b0a316ea8e4c" : {
      "-Kp0jed1EZ5BLllL5_cm" : {
        "createdAt" : 1.500046597341153E9,
        "groupId" : "fb343534ca520c70fe35b0a316ea8e4c",
        "objectId" : "-Kp0jed1EZ5BLllL5_cl",
        "senderId" : "lI6SRppSboScWo5xVjcfLL82Ogr2",
        "senderName" : "Test1 Test1",
        "status" : "",
        "text" : "hi",
        "type" : "text",
        "updatedAt" : 1.50004659734136E9
      }
    }
  },
  "Recent" : {
    "-Kp0jecwejhzQbbm62CW" : {
      "counter" : 0,
      "createdAt" : 1.500046600967624E9,
      "description" : "Test1 Test1",
      "groupId" : "fb343534ca520c70fe35b0a316ea8e4c",
      "lastMessage" : "hi",
      "members" : [ "lI6SRppSboScWo5xVjcfLL82Ogr2", "fnRvHFpaoDhXqM1se7NoTSiWZIZ2" ],
      "objectId" : "-Kp0jecwejhzQbbm62CV",
      "picture" : "",
      "type" : "private",
      "updatedAt" : 1.500046600967647E9,
      "userId" : "fnRvHFpaoDhXqM1se7NoTSiWZIZ2"
    },
    "-Kp0jed-FU1PXt1iPr29" : {
      "counter" : 0,
      "createdAt" : 1.500046600971885E9,
      "description" : "Srikant Root",
      "groupId" : "fb343534ca520c70fe35b0a316ea8e4c",
      "lastMessage" : "hi",
      "members" : [ "lI6SRppSboScWo5xVjcfLL82Ogr2", "fnRvHFpaoDhXqM1se7NoTSiWZIZ2" ],
      "objectId" : "-Kp0jed-FU1PXt1iPr28",
      "picture" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/top500golfdev/uploads/profile/srikant.yadav@rootinfosol.com/profilepicture.jpg",
      "type" : "private",
      "updatedAt" : 1.500046600971896E9,
      "userId" : "lI6SRppSboScWo5xVjcfLL82Ogr2"
    }
  },
  "User" : {
    "fnRvHFpaoDhXqM1se7NoTSiWZIZ2" : {
      "createdAt" : 1.500045753102713E9,
      "email" : "srikant.yadav@rootinfosol.com",
      "firstname" : "Srikant",
      "fullname" : "Srikant Yadav",
      "handle" : "Srikant",
      "lastname" : "Yadav",
      "networkImage" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/top500golfdev/uploads/profile/srikant.yadav@rootinfosol.com/profilepicture.jpg",
      "objectId" : "fnRvHFpaoDhXqM1se7NoTSiWZIZ2",
      "online" : false,
      "updatedAt" : 1.500045753102731E9
    },
    "lI6SRppSboScWo5xVjcfLL82Ogr2" : {
      "createdAt" : 1.500045791892967E9,
      "email" : "test1@gmail.com",
      "firstname" : "Test1",
      "fullname" : "Test1 Test1",
      "handle" : "test1",
      "lastname" : "Test1",
      "networkImage" : "",
      "objectId" : "lI6SRppSboScWo5xVjcfLL82Ogr2",
      "online" : false,
      "updatedAt" : 1.500046571456235E9
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From scanning code + data it looks like it should work. Can you edit your question to include the JSON as text, so I can give it a try? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Sure will give.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please check my edited answer.